# Finite Resolution by locally free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to figure out how to proof that any coherent module $F$ on $\mathbb P^n$  has a finite resolution by locally free sheaves. Now I read somewhere that it is proved in SGA 6 II.2.7.1 but I am not able to read french texts, even if they are only mathematical texts. So I tried to do it on my own but I did not proceed very far.

I know that I have a surjection $\bigoplus \limits  _{i=0}^n \mathcal O(-d)\rightarrow F$ but how do I proceed from here?

sincerely,slin

Comment: I am definitely not an expert but I would say that the kernel should be supported on a smaller dimensional variety, and induction should give you such a resolution.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71997/locally-free-resolution-of-coherent-sheaf